# Compare values into loop from List

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this code which I want to use to compare values from table

```
        List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();

        list.add("Create Inventory");
        list.add("2021-08-03T12:29:05.123");
 
        // this loop will be executed for 3 iterations
        List<WebElement> eachRow = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@class='ag-center-cols-container']/div[1]/div"));
        for (WebElement column : eachRow)
        {
            // this code will print "Create Inventory" and "2021-08-03T12:29:05.123"
            System.out.println("AssertEquals value " + column.getText());

            Assert.assertEquals(column.getText(), list.iterator().hasNext());
        }
```

The question is how I can synchronize the assertion here: `Assert.assertEquals(column.getText(), list.iterator().hasNext());`

When I find using Selenium some value I want to get next value into the list.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you have 2 columns in each row while in all the rows the first column text is `Create Inventory` and the second column text is `2021-08-03T12:29:05.123`?

Comment: yes, how I can make comparison against the Java list?

Comment: It must be a list? The values and the list length are fixed?

Comment: No, just the values are important. Other Java collection can be used as well if it's ordered.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new actual list and store the `column.getText()` in that for each loop and then compare `list`  and the `actual list`

**Sample code :-**

```
List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
List<String> actualList = new LinkedList<String>();
List<WebElement> eachRow = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@class='ag-center-cols-container']/div[1]/div"));
for (WebElement column : eachRow)
{
    // this code will print "Create Inventory" and "2021-08-03T12:29:05.123"
    System.out.println("AssertEquals value " + column.getText());
    actualList.add(column.getText());
}

boolean equalLists = list.size() == actualList.size() && list.containsAll(actualList);
Assert.assertTrue(equalLists);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use this approach:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

list.add("Create Inventory");
list.add("2021-08-03T12:29:05.123");
 
        // this loop will be executed for 3 iterations
List<WebElement> eachRow = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@class='ag-center-cols-container']/div[1]/div"));
for (int i = 0; i< eachRow.size();i++)
{
    Assert.assertTrue(eachRow.get(i).getText().contentEquals(list.get(i)));
}
```